# Return a 2D array from a function with just the array size as the arguments

Tags: c++

i am new to c++ and i am trying to create an Array from within a function with just the array size, `[row][col]`, as the argument. I know you cannot return an array from a function in c++. I would allocate memory in these situations if i were to code in C. However, i am not sure what is the C++ way (:

I tried,

```
    int** get2Darray(int row, int col){
         int** randInts = new int[row][col]; //Invalid. Constant required.
         return randInts;
    }
```

Thanks.

EDIT: `vector` class does the trick, however, my program is heavily modular. I dont have access to the main program. My function should be called and a fresh array should be created and returned. Implementation should only be done inside this function

Comment: You should return `std::vector<std::vector<int>> &`.

Comment: Am i required to include  any additional libraries?

Comment: yes, `#include <vector>`

Comment: when i return a vector type, would i able to use it on a `int** type`?

Comment: @user859385, you are returning an array of uninitialized pointers.

Comment: @user859385 your solution is broken, see blazs answer - as he points out, it's not the c++ way to do things but it fits your restrictions.

Comment: @blazs i would initialize it... this is just a code fragment.

Comment: @blazs i see my mistake. ill remove the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change `int** randInts = new int[row][col];` into `int* randInts = new int[row * col];` or define `int** randInts` as follows:

```
int** randInts = new int*[row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    randInts[i] = new int[col];
}
```

It's a C way, not a C++ way. In C++ you should use containers (e.g. a vector as suggested in the comments).

Answer (score 3):

I have shown this using `vector <vector<T> >`, but you can also use Eigen matrix or `boost::ublas::matrix`

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > foo(const int rows, const int cols)
{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
    v.resize(rows);
    for (auto i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        v[i].resize(cols);
    }
    return v;
}
```

This will return a matrix of desired dimensions, and all elements will be initialized to `0`.

The `std::move` part invokes a behavior called move semantics. You can read up on it. It's basically a better way of returning objects across a function boundary.

For compatibility's sake, if you must have a native array, then do this :

```
std::vector< vector<int> > temp = foo(rows, cols);
int *v = &temp[0][0];
```

Now, you can implement the gymnastics to get the correct index inside of `int *v`. You don't need multiple indirection.

P.S. This implementation assumes that your compiler supports C++ 11.

Comment: You should probably mention this is C++11.

Comment: @blazs agree. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the return type of the function be non-void?

Comment: Adding the explicit `std::move` forces the compiler to move rather than RVO. Don't do it.

Comment: @kfsone Can you please explain this? If you don't do explicit `std::move`, does the compiler still know to return with move semantics instead of performing a deep copy?

Comment: I need to be able to return an int 2d array. Not a vector type. My program is heavily modulated. I wont be able to have access to the main function. They should be able to call the my function and get a 2d array. Ill update this on the post.

Comment: It knows to do Return Value Optimization. Scott Meyers explains it in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smqT9Io_bKo

Comment: @kfsone Interesting. I will check up on this in the evening, and update my code if needed.

Comment: @FirstJens saw it. However, this still requires implementation OUTSIDE the function. Thank you. However, i found a way after messing around.

Comment: @FirstJens See http://ideone.com/OqHHzG note how "without move" directly constructs into the return value not using an intermediate.